# Usuário logado consegue entrar na pagina login

Tags: php, login, session

quando o usuario faz login ele cria sessoes e vai para o painel, mas ele continua com acesso a pagina de login.
como mandar ele de volta ao painel.php quando ele tentar ir para a pagina de login?

sessoes:

```
$user = $_POST['usuario'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
$_SESSION['status'] = 'LOGADO';
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $busca ['usuario'];
$_SESSION['senha'] = $busca ['senha'];
```

Comment: Simplesmente faça um if conferindo a sessão. Se tiver aberta ou algum valor específico setado, redirecione a painel.php com script ou header.

Comment: ah .-. mds obrigado kkk deu certo  if($_SESSION['status'] = 'LOGADO' ) {
     header('Location: painel.php');
    }

Comment: @CryptorWings lembrando que se você usar $_SESSION['status'] = 'LOGADO' sempre vai ser verdadeiro, pois o operador de comparação é == e não =

Comment: Eu não entendo esse costume que eu vejo bastante em PHP de ficar dando redirect. Não é muito mais simples um "if logado include( painel ) else include ( formulário de login)? Foi só um exemplo, tem mil maneiras mais interessantes que redirect, que de brinde ainda permitem que o usuário continue a sessão da página em que parou (apesar de o redirect ser ótimo pra trocar um POST por um GET, mas aí a finalidade já é outra)

Comment: E, olhando por outro lado, qual o problema dele ter acesso ao login? Talvez seja até útil caso ele queira logar em outra conta. Nada que um "if logado echo 'você já está logado como José. clique aqui para ir para o painel, ou use os campos abaixo para logar em outra conta'.

Comment: @Bacco eu uso dessa forma que disse, com include. Como estava por celular, não deu para postar a resposta mais completa. Aliás, até gostaria de conhecer outras formas como você disse. Ajuda nós ae 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2 exemplos:

#### Opção 1

*(terá que alterar sua estrutura)*

Você dará o `include` conforme logado ou não:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
   include_once 'painel.php';
} else {
   include_once 'login.php;
}
```

#### Opção 2

*(para seu caso de não deixar entrar na página de login, e não alterar sua estrutura)*

Verifica na página login se existe a sessão, caso sim, direciona para a página do conteúdo:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['status'])) header('Location: painel.php');
```